# How do I print greek letters in jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook

If I say

```
plt.title(r'$\tau$')
```

or

```
plt.xlabel(r'$\tau$')
```

In `jupyter` notebook, I get the greek letter tau.

How do I do the same for just text?

This doesn't work:

```
print(r'$\tau$', tau)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it works in the first example is that matplotlib [supports](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) TeX markup in any matplotlib text string but python doesn't.

Nevertheless, there are many other ways to do so in python. e.g. you can use escape sequence [`\N{name}`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) to print unicode characters.

```
>>> print('\N{greek small letter tau}')
τ
```

Or you can use [`unicodedata.lookup`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.lookup):

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> print(unicodedata.lookup('greek small letter tau'))
τ
```

---

Also, note that the [default encoding](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support) for python source code is utf-8, so you can simply include a unicode character in a string literal e.g.

```
>>> print('τ')
τ
```

Comment: If you know the required character's Unicode value (for example τ is decimal 964 or hex 03c4) you can also use a Unicode escape such as `"u\03c4"`. This is handy when you just need the occasional symbol and don't want to find its keyboard equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is specific to Jupyter, why not just use Jupyter capability of rendering latex?

```
from IPython.display import display, Latex
display(Latex(r'$\tau$'))
```